# DC barchart how to delimit the x-axis range using the mouse

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to delimit an x-axis range using the mouse like in the image shown:

[image: Bar chart]

But I can't figure out how to make it work.

I'm using d3.js v5.7.0 and dc.js v3.0.7

My code is:

```
    var barChart = dc.barChart("#barChartbar1");
var dimensionbar1 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.airline; });
var groupbar1 = dimensionbar1.group().reduceCount();
var yMax = groupbar1.size();

var keys = groupbar1.all().filter(function(d) {return d.key});
var xRange =[]
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length;i++) {
    xRange.push(keys[i].key);
}

barChart
.width(450).height(400)
.margins({top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 60, left: 60})
.x(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(xRange))
.y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,500]).range([400,0]))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.barPadding(.2)
.brushOn(true)
.elasticX(true)
.elasticY(true)
.xAxisLabel("Airline")
.yAxisLabel("FP")
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.dimension(dimensionbar1)
.group(groupbar1)
.renderLabel(true)
.controlsUseVisibility(true)
.centerBar(true)
.on("pretransition", function(chart) {chart.selectAll("rect.bar").on("click",function(d) {chart.filter(null).filter(d.data.key).redrawGroup();})})
.renderlet(function (chart) {chart.selectAll('g.x text').attr('transform','translate(-20,15) rotate(315)')});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get accepted. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you be more specific about what's not working? You have circled the handles in your screenshot, do you mean that brushing works but these handles are not displayed? Are you using dc.css?

Comment: The handler are not displayed and I can't make the filtering (something like the shown in the image). Sorry for not being more clear but I did know how to explain it.

Comment: Aha, I guess it is allowing you to click on individual bars but not brush. That is the supported behavior for charts with an ordinal X scale/units. Currently [brushing an ordinal chart is not supported](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/348); the issue describes a complicated workaround. If possible, it's better if you use a quantitative scale if you want brushing.

Comment: Thank you for your help!